# close an iframe from inside the iframe (it's possible to close a iframe using window.close() inside the iframe)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `iframe` that loads a 3rd party website, this website have one button close that has  the code `javascript:window.close()`.

This code closes if I open that website in a window, but I'm using a `modalbox` and an `iframe`. Is it possible to close the `modalbox` when I click in the 3rd party site that has the code `javascript:window.close()` ?

Comment: the answer is likely: No way

Comment: `top.close();` This will only work if they share the same domain.

Comment: As they don't if they are 3rd party